# Refresh All is not updating refresh-able web query table in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, office365, office-2016

Recently I have updated two of my office PCs with Windows 10 and Office 2016.

I work on Excel sheets (on my server). My excel sheet contains many pages in which data is put as refresh-able web query from our company website.

In one of my new PCs (client) Excel sheets (stored in the server) are working fine and updating data by refresh all command however in my other new PC refresh all command is not updating the same sheet on sever.

I have already checked following :

1. Created new Excel sheet in both of the PCs and put new refresh-able web query data in each. Again first Pc's sheet is getting refreshed by refresh all command but 2nd PC's sheet is not.
2. I have checked data connection setting in both PCs, trust center setting in both, pivot table setting in both PCs, macro setting in both they are perfectly the same in both PCs.
3. Connection setting: update by refresh-all: checked
   External Data: enabled.
   Refresh in the background: doesn't make any changes in the result
   Macro enable or disable: does not make any change in result
   Active X control setting does not make any change in the result 
   trusted doc setting same result
   Option: advance: setting are also same

Please help me to resolve this typical issue... thanks in advance.
I am really puzzled because I did not make any settings changes in these brand new PCs with installed Office 2016. 
But not able to work on one PC as my Excel sheets are not refreshing data from the website in one PC.